# ruby convert array to hash preserve duplicate key

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, type-conversion

I need to pull down the result of git ls-remote into an array, then convert that array to a hash like this: {commit_hash => reference}.  Occasionally, two commit hashes are identical (but have different references, perhaps).  So I get this kind of thing:

```
["19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06","refs/heads/auto",
 "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d","refs/heads/callout_hooks",  
 "3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8","refs/heads/elab",
 "d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587","refs/heads/elab_6.1",
 "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06","refs/heads/master",
 "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7","refs/heads/regression"]
```

which I want to convert to:

```
{"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06" => "refs/heads/auto"...}
```

but master and auto have the same hash, so one of them gets dropped in the conversion.

How do I either 1.) get a list of the values which were dropped in the conversion, or 2.) make the keys unique by adding a special character to the key, like a *?

Comment: your array elements are not valid in Ruby... Are they array of strings ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope you would like this :

```
ary = [
       "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06","refs/heads/auto",
       "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d","refs/heads/callout_hooks",  
       "3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8","refs/heads/elab",
       "d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587","refs/heads/elab_6.1",
       "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06","refs/heads/master",
       "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7","refs/heads/regression"
     ]

array_hash = ary.each_slice(2).with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = []}) do |(k,v),hash|
  hash[k] << v 
end

# the main advantage is here you wouldn't loose any data, all are with you. You can
# use it as per your need. I think it is a better approach to deal with your situation.
array_hash
# => {"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"=>
#      ["refs/heads/auto", "refs/heads/master"],
#     "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d"=>["refs/heads/callout_hooks"],
#     "3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8"=>["refs/heads/elab"],
#     "d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587"=>["refs/heads/elab_6.1"],
#     "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7"=>["refs/heads/regression"]}
```

Comment: Arup, I believe `with_object` is enough.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes.. you are right.. as `#each_slice` is giving an `Enumerator`, so `#with_object` is enough. Thanks for your review..

Answer (score 5):

If you make a hash of hash_value => array of refs, you'll keep everything:

```
array = ["19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06","refs/heads/auto",
 "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d","refs/heads/callout_hooks",  
 "3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8","refs/heads/elab",
 "d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587","refs/heads/elab_6.1",
 "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06","refs/heads/master",
 "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7","refs/heads/regression"
]

array.each_slice(2).reduce({}) { |h, (k, v)| (h[k] ||= []) << v; h }
```

Looks like Arup and I were thinking the same way...

Comment: Nick, perhaps `each_with_object`, rather than `reduce`, to get rid of that unsightly `; h`.  (Recall block variables are ordered differently.)  Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You gave two options for what you want to do:

- Get a list of the values which were dropped in the conversion
- Make the keys unique by adding a special character to the key

I think the second approach is a bad idea, for a couple of reasons: a) you would have to have a method of modifying the key that would allow for the possibility of their being multiple duplicates; and b) making connections between the original and the duplicates would be awkward.  Also, it would be just plain ugly.

I see others have suggested a third possibility: changing the form of the resulting hash, so that values arrays of strings. That might serve you well, but it is not what you asked for, so I chose to build a list of the values that are dropped; i.e., all but the first.

**Code**

```
def create_hash_and_save_extras(arr)
  arr.each_slice(2).with_object([{},[]]) { |(k,v),(h,ex)|
    h.update({k=>v}) { |k, ov, nv| ex << {k=>nv}; ov } }
end
```

**Example**

```
create_hash_and_save_extras(arr)
  #=> [{"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"=>"refs/heads/auto",
  #     "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d"=>"refs/heads/callout_hooks",
  #     "3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8"=>"refs/heads/elab",
  #     "d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587"=>"refs/heads/elab_6.1",
  #     "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7"=>"refs/heads/regression"},
  #   [{"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"=>"refs/heads/master"}]]
```

**Explanation**

[Enumerable#each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) sent to `arr` returns an enumerator:

```
enum1 = arr.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #      "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06", "refs/heads/auto",
  #      "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d", "refs/heads/callout_hooks",
  #      ...
  #      "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7", "refs/heads/regression"
  #   ]:each_slice(2)>
```

[Enumerator#with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) creates an array consisting of and initially-empty hash (represented by the block variable `h`) and an initially-empty array (for the "extras"), represented by the block variable `ex`, which is then sent to `enum1` to create another enumerator (which you can think of as a "compound enumerator"--note the reference to `each_slice(2)>:with_object({})` below).

```
enum2 = enum1.with_object([{},[]])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [
  #      "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06", "refs/heads/auto",
  #      "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d", "refs/heads/callout_hooks",
  #      ...
  #      "906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7", "refs/heads/regression"
  #   ]:each_slice(2)>:with_object([{},[])>
```

We can convert `enum2` to an array to see what it will be passing into its block:

```
enum2.to_a
#=> [[["19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06", "refs/heads/auto"],
#       [{}, []]],
#    [["8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d", "refs/heads/callout_hooks"],
#       [{}, []]],
#    [["3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8", "refs/heads/elab"],
#       [{}, []]],
#    [["d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587", "refs/heads/elab_6.1"],
#       [{}, []]],
#    [["19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06", "refs/heads/master"],
#       [{}, []]],
#    [["906dfe6eebff832baf0f92683d751432fcc98ab7", "refs/heads/regression"],
#       [{}, []]],
```

The first element that `enum2` passes into its block is

```
[["19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06", "refs/heads/auto"], [{}, []]]]]
```

The block variables are therefore assigned as follows:

```
k => "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"
v => "refs/heads/auto"
h => {}
ex = []
```

We now use [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) to merge `{k,v}` into `h` (`h` initially being empty.)  Therefore

```
h.update({k=>v}) { |k, ov, nv| extras << {k=>nv}; ov }
```

becomes

```
h.update({"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"=>"refs/heads/auto"})
```

followed by the block

```
{ |k, ov, nv| ex << {k=>nv}; ov }
```

but the block only applies when the hash merged hash (`h`) and the hash being merged (`update`'s argument) share the same key `k`, in which case `ov` and `nv` are the values associated with those keys for `h` and the hash being merged, respectively.  The merged value for key `k` will be whatever is returned by the block.  Yes, that will apply when we encounter duplicates.

So now

```
h #=> {"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"=>"refs/heads/auto"}
```

We continue in this way for each of the other elements of `enum2`.  When we encounter

```
k = "19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"
v = "refs/heads/master"
h = {"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06"=>"refs/heads/auto",
      "8f6f47c6e8023540b022586e368c68e1e814ce6d"=>"refs/heads/callout_hooks",
      "3cbdb4b2fcb85bc7f0ed08b62e2bf2445a7659e8"=>"refs/heads/elab",
      "d38a9a26ef887c08b306bdab210b39882f58e587"=>"refs/heads/elab_6.1"}
```

we find that `k` is already in the merged hash `h`, so the block is evaluated to determine the value of `k` in the merged hash `h`.  We want to keep the current value `h[k]`, which is `ov`, so that is what the block returns.  First, however, we append the (still empty) array `ex` with the duplicate value, expressed as a hash.

```
ex << {"19d97e408ee3f993745b053e281ac9dc69519e06" => "refs/heads/master"}
```